# VLC start up with playlist

Tags: vlc-media-player

What is the command line for vlc to start up playing a specific playlist?
something like this: START /WAIT C:\"Program Files"\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe %1 playlist="c:\users\rendszergazda\desktop\p.xspf" vlc://quit
shutdown -s -t 60

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to ask this! Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `--playlist` option.

```
vlc.exe --playlist C:/PlaylistLocation
```

Here you start the vlc with the playlist-parameter and you specify, where the playlist is located.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you could use the `--started-from-file` option.

```
vlc.exe --started-from-file PATH_TO_PLAYLIST
```

OR, just run:

```
vlc.exe PATH_TO_PLAYLIST
```

In your case, the `PATH_TO_PLAYLIST` could be replaced by `"c:\users\rendszergazda\desktop\p.xspf"`

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining this option.